# neural network for handwritten recognition?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I have been following the course of Andrew Ng about Machine Learning, and I currently have some doubts about the implementation of a handwritten recognition tool.

-First he says that he uses a subset of the MNIST dataset, which contaings 5000 training examples and each training example is an image in a 20x20 gray scale format. With that he says that we have a vector of 400 elements of length that is the "unrolled" of the data previously described. Does it mean that the train set has something like the following format?

```
Training example 1 v[1,2,...,400]
Training example 2 v[1,2,...,400]
...
Training example 5000 v[1,2,...,400]
```

For the coding part the author gives the following complete code in Matlab:

```
%% Machine Learning Online Class - Exercise 3 | Part 2: Neural Networks

%  Instructions
%  ------------
% 
%  This file contains code that helps you get started on the
%  linear exercise. You will need to complete the following functions 
%  in this exericse:
%
%     lrCostFunction.m (logistic regression cost function)
%     oneVsAll.m
%     predictOneVsAll.m
%     predict.m
%
%  For this exercise, you will not need to change any code in this file,
%  or any other files other than those mentioned above.
%

%% Initialization
clear ; close all; clc

%% Setup the parameters you will use for this exercise
input_layer_size  = 400;  % 20x20 Input Images of Digits
hidden_layer_size = 25;   % 25 hidden units
num_labels = 10;          % 10 labels, from 1 to 10   
                          % (note that we have mapped "0" to label 10)

%% =========== Part 1: Loading and Visualizing Data =============
%  We start the exercise by first loading and visualizing the dataset. 
%  You will be working with a dataset that contains handwritten digits.
%

% Load Training Data
fprintf('Loading and Visualizing Data ...\n')

load('ex3data1.mat');
m = size(X, 1);

% Randomly select 100 data points to display
sel = randperm(size(X, 1));
sel = sel(1:100);

displayData(X(sel, :));

fprintf('Program paused. Press enter to continue.\n');
pause;

%% ================ Part 2: Loading Pameters ================
% In this part of the exercise, we load some pre-initialized 
% neural network parameters.

fprintf('\nLoading Saved Neural Network Parameters ...\n')

% Load the weights into variables Theta1 and Theta2
load('ex3weights.mat');

%% ================= Part 3: Implement Predict =================
%  After training the neural network, we would like to use it to predict
%  the labels. You will now implement the "predict" function to use the
%  neural network to predict the labels of the training set. This lets
%  you compute the training set accuracy.

pred = predict(Theta1, Theta2, X);

fprintf('\nTraining Set Accuracy: %f\n', mean(double(pred == y)) * 100);

fprintf('Program paused. Press enter to continue.\n');
pause;

%  To give you an idea of the network's output, you can also run
%  through the examples one at the a time to see what it is predicting.

%  Randomly permute examples
rp = randperm(m);

for i = 1:m
    % Display 
    fprintf('\nDisplaying Example Image\n');
    displayData(X(rp(i), :));

    pred = predict(Theta1, Theta2, X(rp(i),:));
    fprintf('\nNeural Network Prediction: %d (digit %d)\n', pred, mod(pred, 10));

    % Pause
    fprintf('Program paused. Press enter to continue.\n');
    pause;
end
```

and the predict function should be complete by the students, I have done the following:

```
function p = predict(Theta1, Theta2, X)
%PREDICT Predict the label of an input given a trained neural network
%   p = PREDICT(Theta1, Theta2, X) outputs the predicted label of X given the
%   trained weights of a neural network (Theta1, Theta2)

% Useful values
m = size(X, 1);
num_labels = size(Theta2, 1);

% You need to return the following variables correctly 
p = zeros(size(X, 1), 1);
X = [ones(m , 1) X];
% ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
% Instructions: Complete the following code to make predictions using
%               your learned neural network. You should set p to a 
%               vector containing labels between 1 to num_labels.
%
% Hint: The max function might come in useful. In particular, the max
%       function can also return the index of the max element, for more
%       information see 'help max'. If your examples are in rows, then, you
%       can use max(A, [], 2) to obtain the max for each row.
%

a1 = X;
a2 = sigmoid(a1*Theta1');
a2 = [ones(m , 1) a2];
a3 = sigmoid(a2*Theta2');
[M , p] = max(a3 , [] , 2);
```

Even thought it runs I am not completely aware of how it really works (I have just followed the step by step instructions that is on the author's website). I have doubts in the following:

- The author considers that X(input) is an array of 5000 x 400 elements, or it has 400 neurons as input, with 10 neurons as output and a hidden layer. Does it mean this 5000 x 400 values are the training set?
- The author gives us the values of theta 1 and theta 2, which I believe serve as weights for the calculations on the inner layer, but how does values are obtained? Why does he uses 25 neurons of hidden layer and not 24 or 30?

Any help will be apreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I took that course last year. There is Coursera forum associated with each class, and divided into subjects for each week's assignments. I think you will find it much more open and useful for learning the coursework than posting to Stack Overflow. Though I suspect you will find a few people who, like me, completed the course in the past here, Stack Overflow does not support you and allow for chat about the questions with the other students in the same way that Coursera will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break your question in parts:

> First he says that he uses a subset of the MNIST dataset, which
>   contaings 5000 training examples and each training example is an image
>   in a 20x20 gray scale format. With that he says that we have a vector
>   of 400 elements of length that is the "unrolled" of the data
>   previously described. Does it mean that the train set has something
>   like the following format? (...)

You're on the right track. Each training example is a 20x20 image. The simplest neural network model, introduced in the course, treats each image just as a simple 1x400 vector (the "unrolled" means exactly this transformation). The dataset is stored in a matrix because this way you can perform computations faster exploiting the efficient linear algebra libraries which are used by Octave/Matlab. You don't need necessarily to store all training examples as a 5000x400 matrix, but this way your code will run faster.

> The author considers that X(input) is an array of 5000 x 400 elements,
>   or it has 400 neurons as input, with 10 neurons as output and a hidden
>   layer. Does it mean this 5000 x 400 values are the training set?

The "input layer" is nothing but the very input image. You can think of it as neurons whose output values were already calculated or as the values were coming from outside the network (think about your retina. It is like the input layer of you visual system). Thus this network has 400 input units (the "unrolled" 20x20 image). But of course, your training set doesn't consist of a single image, thus you put all your 5000 images together in a single 5000x400 matrix to form your training set.

> The author gives us the values of theta 1 and theta 2, which I believe
>   serve as weights for the calculations on the inner layer, but how does
>   values are obtained?

These theta values were found using a algorithm called backpropagation. If you didn't have to implement it in the course yet, just be patient. It might be in the exercises soon! Btw, yes they are the weights.

> Why does he uses 25 neurons of hidden layer and not 24 or 30?

He probably chose an arbitrarily value that doesn't run too slow, neither has too poor performance. You probably can find much better values for this hyper-parameters. But if you increase it too much, the training procedure will take probably much longer. Also since you are just using a small portion of the hole training set (the original MNIST has 60000 training examples and 28x28 images), you need to use a "small" number of hidden units to prevent over fitting. If you use too many units your neurons will "learn by heart" the training examples and will not be able to generalize to new unseen data. Finding the hyper parameters, such as the number of the hidden units, is a kind of art that you will master with experience (and maybe with Bayesian optimization and more advanced method, but that's another story xD).

Answer (score 2):

I did the same course some time ago.

X is the input data. Therefore X is the matrix consisting of the 5 000 vectors of 400 elements each. There is no training set, because the network is pre trained.

Normally the values for theta 1 and 2 are trained. How this is done is a subject for the next few lectures. (Backpropagation algorithm)

I'm not entirely sure, why he used 25 neurons as hidden layer. However my guess is, that this number of neurons simply works, without making the training step take forever.

Comment: So there are 2000000 values in training set?

Comment: Sorry it is not the training set. The network is pre trained in this example. X is the data to be evaluated.

Comment: @ThomasPinetz does it mean that there are 5000 cases that the program will try to evaluate?

Comment: well there are 5000 example (20x20) images; but, only 10 possible classes. (i.e. 0-9).  Did you mean something else by 'cases'?